# c# Static method scope issue

Tags: c#, singleton

Im having an issue calling a static method in a static class. I would like to have a very simple log wrapper using NLog, where i call Log.warn etc:

```
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;

namespace Test.Logger
{
  public static class Log
  {
    private static readonly ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static Log()
    {
        logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }


    public static void Debug(string message)
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, message);
    }

  }

}
```

however it seems when i reference a project with the above class, the class itself is visible but the Debug, or any other methods are no longer visible. I have looked into the use of an instance, however would prefer it did not require an instance. Likewise I looked into potential scope issues with static classes, however the log class is infact visible just the public static methods contained in the Log class are not.

This is how I am trying to call the method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Test.Logger;

namespace WpfTestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        Test.Logger.Log.Debug("test message");
        //this method cannot be found, however Test.Logger.Log can
    }
}
```

Comment: `static method in a static class` its actually not a static class, just FYI

Comment: Shouldnt the Log class be static?

Comment: Valid point, i just tested after changing it to static but im still have the same issue, only not obviously i cannot use it as a type and the methods are still not accessible via Log.Debug

Comment: Does this give you a compilation error ? i.e does it build

Comment: No the logger class compiles however the WPF application using Log.Debug() cannot find the Debug method, or anything other than the Log class itself...

Comment: You're calling the method inside the class body, not in a method.

Comment: Yep, that was it.....i cant believe i missed that....thanks for the help

Comment: Wow, that was actually it I can't believe it. Np. Here's a tip for the future: Actually read and understand the error message, don't make assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling the `Log.Debug` method within a class definition. Which (interestingly to me anyway) doesn't work, you need to move it inside a class method:

```
class Program
{
    //doesn't work
    Log.Debug("");



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //works
        Log.Debug("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps